# Is there an Excel function for Comparing Values in 2 Columns and Returning another Value if they match?

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 tables (in Excel), with a list of contacts and addresses in each.
Now, if an address is found in both tables, it needs to insert "True" in a column on one of the tables. If the address is not found in both tables, return "False".
Can someone direct me to a formula for this?

Comment: If you have Office 365, `FILTER` could do the trick. Otherwise, you will have to elaborate on what you are working with, because we can't help you with the information you have provided thus far.

Comment: COUNTIFS() or ISNUMBER(MATCH()) will do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of the two tables add a column and use this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($F$2:$F$6,B2)>0
```

[image]

If you need to check that **both** the contact and address are duplicated then you can use a COUNTIFS function:

```
=COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$6,A2,$F$2:$F$6,B2)>0
```

Comment: Jody, this formula does not work because the tables are on 2 separate sheets.

Comment: @James_ExcelFan Sure it does, you just need to add sheet references to the worksheet ranges.  `=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$E$2:$E$6,Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$F$2:$F$6,Sheet1!B2)>0`